# SQL query to find products which have different values for a particular id which should be the same

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a SQL query which will fetch me the list of products which has different values for a same id and product is of table A and Id and values are of table B and both the tables can be joined by column name prod_id

[image]

Output I want:

- List item

| product |
| --- |
| abc |

So in output I want only the product abc because it has different values for their respective id and I don’t need xyz because it has same values for their respective id

I tried but I’m not getting what I want as mentioned above

Comment: If the answer below does not answer your question (you should find that it does answer the question you originally asked) then [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for sample data that demonstrates the problem (including why the answer does not work); a detailed description of the problem; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: What is a relationship between tables A and B while you show only a single table with different column names (`Product` vs `prod_id`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, you have two tables - one with PROD_ID and PRODUCT and the other with PROD_ID, ID, VALS - something like this:

```sql
WITH
    tbl_a AS
        (
            Select 1 "PROD_ID", 'abc' "PRODUCT" From DUAL Union All
            Select 9 "PROD_ID", 'xyz' "PRODUCT" From DUAL
        ),
    tbl_b AS
        (
            Select 1 "PROD_ID", '10' "ID", 345678 "VALS" From DUAL Union All
            Select 1 "PROD_ID", '10' "ID", 345678 "VALS" From DUAL Union All
            Select 1 "PROD_ID", '14' "ID", 458292 "VALS" From DUAL Union All
            Select 1 "PROD_ID", '13' "ID", 629351 "VALS" From DUAL Union All
            Select 1 "PROD_ID", '13' "ID", 629354 "VALS" From DUAL Union All
            
            Select 9 "PROD_ID", '10' "ID", 375281 "VALS" From DUAL Union All
            Select 9 "PROD_ID", '10' "ID", 375281 "VALS" From DUAL Union All
            Select 9 "PROD_ID", '12' "ID", 826292 "VALS" From DUAL Union All
            Select 9 "PROD_ID", '12' "ID", 826292 "VALS" From DUAL 
        )
```

Now, if this is the case, all you have to do is to join the tables by PROD_ID and select the product having more than one distinct value of VALS column grouped by PRODUCT and ID:

```sql
Select
    a.PRODUCT
From
    tbl_a a
Inner Join
    tbl_b b ON(b.PROD_ID = a.PROD_ID)
Group By
    a.PRODUCT, b.ID
Having
    Count(DISTINCT b.VALS) > 1
--
--  Result:
--  PRODUCT
--  -------
--  abc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct product
from your_table
group by product, id
having count(distinct values) > 1
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a subquery here?

Comment: You are right - Oracle can handle `group by` and `distinct`  in combination: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/705f34/1

Comment: The above provided query gives me no records so I request you please see my question once again

Comment: @AasiyaFathima The query works as demonstrated by the fiddle in the above comment and [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ot1BT2w1) which uses your sample data.

Comment: Since I can’t use the original column names I used a sample name to describe my issue but when I tried with my actual data, it gives me no values

Comment: @AasiyaFathima Then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74598000/edit) to include the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements (as **TEXT** not images) for sample data that is representative of your problem (rather than an overly simplified question that does not represent your problem).